# How to parse value "message" in logstash

Tags: json, parsing, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have setup a small scale of ELK stack in 2 virtual machines with 1 vm for filebeat & 1 for Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana. In Logstash pipeline or indexpartten, how to parse the following part of log in "message" field to separate or extract data?

"message" field:

```
Apr 30 2013 09:22:48: %ASA-5-106100: access-list acl_in permitted tcp inside/10.0.0.13(43013) -> dmz/192.168.33.31(25) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0x71a87d94, 0x0]
```

expected change:

```
{"timestamp":"Ari 30 2013 09:22:48","%ASA-5-106100":"access-list acl_in permitted tcp","inside":"10.0.0.13(43013)","dmz":"192.168.33.31(25)","hit-cnt 1 first hit":"[0x71a87d94, 0x0]"}
```

This is my original log that indexed by logstash:

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-6.8.23-2023.04.10",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "v1Gwa4cBVIEd-qyB6ehj",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "offset": 3847,
    "message": "Apr 30 2013 09:22:48: %ASA-5-106100: access-list acl_in permitted tcp inside/10.0.0.13(43013) -> dmz/192.168.33.31(25) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0x71a87d94, 0x0]",
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "beat": {
      "name": "localhost.localdomain",
      "version": "6.8.23",
      "hostname": "localhost.localdomain"
    },
    "host": {
      "containerized": false,
      "name": "localhost.localdomain",
      "id": "e16def5744db4db7ba8774e4274a19ff",
      "os": {
        "version": "7 (Core)",
        "name": "CentOS Linux",
        "platform": "centos",
        "family": "redhat",
        "codename": "Core"
      },
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    "prospector": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "log": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/var/log/sample.log"
      }
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2023-04-10T15:02:47.859Z",
    "source": "/var/log/sample.log"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-04-10T15:02:47.859Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "log.file.path": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@/var/log/sample.log@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1681138967859
  ]
}
```

Thanks for your help!